# Linear first-order systems of ODEs - Proving linear dependence of a set of function vector solutions on an entire interval from a single point

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

In my Analysis course at university, the professor's textbook describes linear first-order systems of ordinary differential equations, and more precisely, the solutions to the homogeneous equation of the form

$$\vec{Y}\,'(t)=A(t)\vec{Y}(t)$$

where $\vec{Y}(t)$ is a vector of $n$ components that are each a function of $t$. Now, the book states that given $n$ solutions to this equation, $\vec{Y}_1(t) ... \vec{Y}_n(t)$, one can prove that these solutions are linearly dependent or linearly independent on an entire interval $I$ based on just *a single* $t_0\in I$ for which the solutions are one of both. I have spent quite some time trying to wrap my head around the proof, and I can't seem to do it, so I was wondering if anyone could reformulate it, or perhaps point me to appropriate search terms so that I can do my own further reading on the internet.

The proof uses the case of linear dependence, and is as follows:

Suppose $\vec{Y}_1(t) ... \vec{Y}_n(t)$ are solutions to the homogeneous differential equation above, and for a certain $t_0 \in I$, it holds that

$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\;\vec{Y}_i(t_0)=\vec0$$

with not all $c_i=0$. Then, there can be defined a vector function $\vec{Y}_{total}(t)$ that is this linear combination, for which - by linearity - the differential equations above holds. This same $\vec{Y}_{total}(t)$ can then be seen as the solution to the initial value problem $\vec{Y}\,'(t)=A(t)\vec{Y}(t)$ with $\vec{Y}_{total}(t_0)=\vec0$. *Thus, because of the uniqueness of a solution, it must be true that this $\vec{Y}_{total}(t)$ is the trivial solution,* proving the linear dependence of $\vec{Y}_1(t) ... \vec{Y}_n(t)$ on the entire interval $I$.

It is this final step in italics I am just not getting. How so does "uniqueness of a solution" come into play here? It baffles me every time I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume $A$ is continuous matrix function defined on some interval $[a,b]$ and you are interested in solutions to the linear first order system $\vec{Y}'(t) = A(t) \vec{Y}(t)$. The basic uniqueness result tells you that if you fix a certain point $t_0 \in [a,b]$  and you have two (continuously differentiable) solutions $\vec{Y}_1,\vec{Y}_2$ to the ODE which satisfy $\vec{Y}_1(t_0) = \vec{Y}_2(t_0)$ (that is, they both satisfy the same initial conditions at $t = t_0$), then they must agree on all points of the interval $[a,b]$.

Given this uniqueness result, the logic of the proof is as follows:

1. Assume you have $n$ solutions $\vec{Y}_1,\dots,\vec{Y}_n$ to the equation which are linearly dependent at $t = t_0$ so that
   $$ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \vec{Y}_i(t_0) = \vec{0} $$
   for some $c_1,\dots,c_n$, not all zero.
2. Define $\vec{Y}(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i Y_i(t)$ and $\vec{Z}(t) \equiv \vec{0}$ (the trivial solution). Note that using the linearity of the ODE, both $\vec{Y},\vec{Z}$ satisfy the ODE. That is,
   $$ \vec{Y}'(t) = A(t)\vec{Y}(t), \vec{Z}'(t) = A(t)\vec{Z}(t). $$
3. In addition, $\vec{Z}(t_0) = \vec{Y}(t_0) = \vec{0}$. Hence, by uniqueness we must have $\vec{Z}(t) = \vec{Y}(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ so in fact for all $t_1 \in [a,b]$ we have
   $$ \vec{Y}(t_1) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \vec{Y}_i(t_1) = \vec{0} $$
   which shows that $(\vec{Y}_1(t_1), \dots, \vec{Y}_n(t_1))$ are also linearly dependent for all $t_1 \in [a,b]$.

Comment: Ah, very interesting; I didn't know that is what uniqueness implied. So then, what does this tell us about $Y_{total}$ -- does it mean the zero vector is the unique solution to the differential equation, or is this just the differential equation telling us "This ain't it, chief", with a non-zero solution yet to be found?

Comment: @Mew: The uniqueness tells you that if you have a solution to the ODE which vanishes at some point $t_0$, it must vanish on all other points of the interval. Another way of saying it is that the zero vector is the unique solution to the differential equation which satisfies the condition $\vec{Y}(t_0) = \vec{0}$.